# How to do mount/unmount effects with exhaustive-deps lint rule

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I'm having trouble understanding how to do the equivalent to `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` with `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint rule is in my application.  For instance on loading a component I want to load some data and clean it up after I'm finished.  So I might write something along these lines.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  loadDataById(id, other, properties);
  return () => {
    resetDataById(id);
  };
}, []);
```

The trouble is now that we've included the react-hooks lint rules.  It's suggesting that I'd need to include `id`, `other`, and `properties` in the dependency list in this example.  But if I do that, the `loadDataById` and `resetDataById` methods will get called when `other`, and `properties` change, but I *only* want these on load/unload of the component.  I've fallen back on just disabling that lint rule on those specific lines, but that seems like an anti-pattern for something that will be reasonably common in our application.

Comment: No, disabling it is not an antipattern. The rule exists to fix mistakes when hook input was left empty by mistake. If you believe the effect should run once, it should be done the way you did it.

Answer (score 2):

If you believe that your hook should only run once and only once, even if the dependencies change. You can always ignore that eslint rule using a comment directive, like this:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  loadDataById(id, other, properties);
  return () => {
    resetDataById(id);
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [useMount](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useMount.md) and [useUnmount](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useUnmount.md) hooks from [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) library, or write your own. They don't require deps array and are more explicit for such use cases.

```js
useMount(() => loadDataById(id, other, properties));
useUnmount(() => resetDataById(id));
```

Also if your functions doesn't require parameters it will look simplier like:

```js
useMount(loadData);
useUnmount(resetState);
```